# Extract binary representation of an audio file

Tags: audio, binary, extract, speech

i'd like to extract the exact binary implementation from an audio file (maybe recorded in audacity). i want this to extract those representation to recognize speech and sound i.e. a basic speech recognition software.

the audio file may also be .mp3 or .wav . please help

EDIT-
I want to obtain the waveform of the audio not as a graph but as the binary representation so that I can convert the speech to text.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the exact binary implementation from an audio file"? If you mean the file format details, you can have a look at this for WAV files: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Comment: All files are by default binary. You should edit your answer if you mean extract the audio waveform as an array (of floats or binary words) along with necessary metadata to play it back, like sampling rate.

Comment: Read up on the format of WAV files.  MP3 files are more complicated and you probably don't want to fool with those right away -- WAV files will let you "cut your teeth".

Answer (score 1):

A basic WAV file consists of a header (I'm thinking about 60 bytes long) and then the actual data.

The data consists of sets of integers.  One set of integers is produced for each "sample", which may be 8000 times a second or 44000 times a second or some other sample rate.

A single set of integers (representing a single sample) consists of one integer for each channel, which may in theory be any number but is generally either 1 (mono) or 2 (stereo).  Each individual integer may be 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes long.

The individual integer represents the sound level of that channel at that particular instant in time.  If the sound being represented was a sine wave, the value of the integer would be `V * sin(K * t)`, where `V` is the volume, `K` is some constant, and `t` is the current time.  Note that the integer is signed, and the "sound level" can be negative or positive at any particular moment (and will generally be negative about half the time).
The sample rate, number of channels, and size of an individual channel value are all encoded in fields in the header (along with several other pieces of information).

In general, to extract the frequency of the signal you apply a [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to the binary sound data, to convert from the "time domain" to the "frequency domain".  This would generally be done between about 5 an 50 times a second, depending on the sample rate and other factors.  (There are several open source FFT libraries available.)  However, speech recognition employs a number of other algorithms as well.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. basically, i wanna design a basic voice recognition software. can you please help how to go about  it. even after your explanation i'm kind of lost.i wanna use hidden markov model to desing the software

Comment: @SKC -- If you want to design voice recognition software you're going to have to do a lot of research.  I'm guessing that, working part time 10-20 hours a week, it would take a year to get something that sorta works, starting from zero.

Comment: ok. but i'm looking something very very basic. controlling a media player perhaps. like play pause etc. as a mini project.